# Special characteres <, >, ", and & in XML in Flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex, character

How to use special characteres like <,>,", and & in XML in Flex?

Example: i have

```
xmlList = <permission id="1" label="true"/>;
```

and

```
xml = <item id="1" permission="" />
```

i do this:

```
xml.@permission = xmlList.toString();
```

but after all this is the result =

```
<item id="1" permission="&lt;permission id=&quot;1&quot; label=&quot;true&quot;/&gt;" />
```

I need that the special characters remain in your original format. Some help?

Thanks.

Comment: The characters in their original format does not consitute valid XML, are you sure you wan't to embed an XML element inside an XML attribute, or are you looking for something else (e.g. try converting permission attribute to an element)

Comment: I do this because on another screen, i need of the information like XML that are within @permission. And the xmlList can not be a children because in 'xml' there are other different children already. I will try to convert to an element.

Comment: My boss informed me that I was doing wrong. He told me to add another child with kind permission and give the appendChild XMLList within it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing `xml.@permission = xmlList.toString()` you can do `xml.appendChild(xmlList)`, which results in:

```
<item id="1">
    <permission id="1" label="true"/>
</item>
```

You can then access the permission xml element by using `xml.permission`